# Javascript: How do I fire an event as a result of a change to multiple textboxes?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, addeventlistener

I am building a sample application, a mockup of a medical records system, using Oracle Apex.  On one page, the object is to enter patient vitals.  What is required is that, once the patient's height (feet and inches) and weight are entered, which are three separate textboxes, the BMI is automatically calculated.  I attempted to set this using dynamic actions, but the result was that, anytime any one of the textboxes was changed, the calculation would fire.  I would like this calculation to only fire if and only if all three textboxes have both been changed and have valid data.  Listed below is the current status of the Javascript function:

```
  function getBMI() {
  var feet = parseInt(document.getElementById('P601_HEIGHTFT').value);
  var inches = parseInt(document.getElementById('P601_HEIGHTIN').value);
  var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById('P601_WEIGHT').value);
  var height = (feet * 12) + inches;
  var warning = document.getElementById('BMIWarning');

  while ((feet == '') && (inches == '') && (weight == '')) {
    document.getElementById('P601_BMI').value = '';
  }

  var BMI = (weight / Math.pow(height, 2)) * 703;
  document.getElementById('P601_BMI').value = BMI.toFixed(2);

  if(BMI < 18.5) {
    warning.style.color = "red";
    warning.innerHTML = "Patient is underweight";
  } else if (BMI >= 18.5 && BMI < 25.0) {
    warning.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (BMI >= 25.0 && BMI <= 29.9) {
    warning.style.color = "red";
    warning.innerHTML = "Patient is overweight";
  } else if (BMI > 29.9) {
    warning.style.color = "red";
    warning.innerHTML = "Patient is obese";
  }

}
```

While it would function properly after all values were entered, the fact that the function fired after each individual textbox was highly undesired.

Comment: Are you calling ```getBMI``` in onchange or onsubmit or any event? If so, you could call another function instead that checks whether all 3 inputs were filled and if so calls ```getBMI```

Comment: You can't set event when 3 text boxes are changed, and you can't change 3 input fields at the same time. You need to listen for each input change, and in function check are all 3 fields populated. Also instead of `onchange` try to use `onblur` (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp). That event is fired when user changed focus from active input field

Comment: Store the values first...then check if all 3 are different

Comment: I ultimately did a combination of all of these:
Stored the values necessary, called a function that evaluated the validity of each, ensuring that all had proper values before calling the function (fired by `onblur`) that would, ultimately, perform the calculation and populate the necessary field.  This also helped me with other fields on that page.  Oracle Apex is an interesting creature.